# Composer invalid Argument exception PHP requirement (7.2.10)

Tags: magento2, composer

I'm trying to install a custom Magento2 module using composer.

The module version is 2.4.0, here below my composer.json file:

```
{
  "name": "fattura24/app-fatturazione",
  "description": "Module to add Fattura24 to Magento2",
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.22|~5.6.0|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0|~7.2.0|~7.2.10"
  },
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "2.4.0",
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Fattura24\\AppFatturazione\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

I open the terminal and I type:

```
composer require Fattura24/app-fatturazione
```

as a result I get this error message:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                   
  Package Fattura24/app-fatturazione at version  has a PHP re  
  quirement incompatible with your PHP version (7.2.10)
```

then I checked my php version by `php -v` command, and I got this result:

```
PHP 7.2.10 (cli) (built: Oct  9 2018 14:56:43) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

Any suggestions? thanks to all

P.S.: by using the command `composer require Fattura24/app-fatturazione --ignore-platform-reqs` I succeeded in installing a previous version of the plugin, but I want to get the latest.

Comment: which Magento version you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should remove `~7.2.0|~7.2.10` from `composer.json`**

> Change PHP version according to your Magento version, refer below link if you're using Magento 2.2.x

**https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html**

For Magento 2.3.x

**https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html**

> **You should only use PHP version 7.2 when you're working on Magento 2.3.x**